# Subscribe to a Gazebo topic and publish in a ROS node

Tags: gazebo, topic, turtlebot3, publisher, node

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi.
My idea is quite simple. Launching the turtlebot3 simulation, I would like to get /LaserScan information from gazebo and use it in a ROS node. Is there any example I can follow? I would like to do it in only one .pp file, not 2 separated (like the talker/listener tutorial).

Any help or reference would be really appreciated!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/274011/subscribe-to-a-gazebo-topic-and-publish-in-a-ros-node/) by [polde](https://answers.ros.org/users/32229/polde/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2017-10-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you are working with that [turtlebot3 simulation](https://turtlebot3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/simulation.html), you don't have to subscribe a gazebo topic, since the simulation is configured already with ROS.

In order to have the turtlebot3 simulation running, I've cloned these packages:

```
git clone https://github.com/ROBOTIS-GIT/turtlebot3_simulations.git
git clone https://github.com/ROBOTIS-GIT/turtlebot3_msgs.git
git clone https://github.com/ROBOTIS-GIT/turtlebot3.git
```

Modified the 2nd line of the launch file **turtlebot3_simulations/turtlebot3_gazebo/launch/turtlebot3_empty_world.launch**, to use the burger model:

```
<launch>
  <arg name="model" default="burger" doc="model type [burger, waffle]"/>
  <arg name="x_pos" default="0.0"/>
  <arg name="y_pos" default="0.0"/>
  <arg name="z_pos" default="0.0"/>

  <include file="$(find gazebo_ros)/launch/empty_world.launch">
    <arg name="world_name" value="$(find turtlebot3_gazebo)/models/empty.world"/>
    <arg name="paused" value="false"/>
    <arg name="use_sim_time" value="true"/>
    <arg name="gui" value="true"/>
    <arg name="headless" value="false"/>
    <arg name="debug" value="false"/>
  </include>

  <param name="robot_description" command="$(find xacro)/xacro.py $(find turtlebot3_description)/urdf/turtlebot3_$(arg model).urdf.xacro" />

  <node name="spawn_urdf" pkg="gazebo_ros" type="spawn_model" args="-urdf -model turtlebot3_burger -x $(arg x_pos) -y $(arg y_pos) -z $(arg z_pos) -param robot_description" />
</launch>
```

And launched like this:

```
roslaunch turtlebot_gazebo turtlebot3_empty_world.launch
```

To subscribe the laser scanner and publish something else in the same node, you can do the following:

Create a pkg with these dependencies

```
catkin_create_pkg my_pkg roscpp std_msgs sensor_msgs
```

Create your node **(src/my_pkg_node.cpp)**

```
#include <ros/ros.h>

#include <sensor_msgs/LaserScan.h>
#include <std_msgs/Int32.h>

ros::Publisher chatter_pub;

void clbk_laser(const sensor_msgs::LaserScan::ConstPtr& msg) {
    ROS_INFO("here we are!!!");
    
    std_msgs::Int32 something_msg;
    something_msg.data = 5;
    
    chatter_pub.publish(something_msg);
    
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    
    ros::init(argc, argv, "my_node");
    
    ros::NodeHandle n;
    
    ros::Subscriber sub_laser = n.subscribe("/scan", 1, clbk_laser);
    
    chatter_pub = n.advertise<std_msgs::Int32>("something", 1);
    
    ros::spin();
    
}
```

Uncomment these lines in your **CMakeLists.txt** file:

```
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME}_node src/my_pkg_node.cpp)

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}_node
  ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
```

I have created a [video](https://youtu.be/2i_iRhzIPfo) showing it step-by-step. I think it's easier to reproduce it.

Hope it can help you!

---

Originally posted by [marcoarruda](https://answers.ros.org/users/25735/marcoarruda/) with karma: 541 on 2017-10-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ArpanHalder](https://answers.ros.org/users/34255/arpanhalder/) on 2018-03-21**:
I have a camera and a laser sensor in the gazebo environment (in the .world SDF file not in the robot model). How to proceed in such case to publish those external sensor data in rostopic.

**Comment by [marcoarruda](https://answers.ros.org/users/25735/marcoarruda/) on 2018-04-27**:
Hi @ArpanHalder, I'm not familiar with SDF but I believe, since that's the native world description of gazebo, you should do that using a gazebo plugin. Almost sure it's not possible to work with it in ROS without a plugin as a bridge.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think the best place to go is on the [how to read gazebo topics](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?cat=guided_i&tut=guided_i5) tutorial, and then [how to publish then to ROS](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?cat=guided_i&tut=guided_i6).

But instead of follow only the two tutorials mentioned (tutorials 5 and 6), I would go from [tutorial 1](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?cat=guided_i&tut=guided_i1) to 6.

---

Originally posted by [Ruben Alves](https://answers.ros.org/users/25452/ruben-alves/) with karma: 1038 on 2017-10-25

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1